# Where we can see microservice request/response payload(json) traffic in Istio

Tags: kubernetes, istio, jaeger

Istio looks very interesting to me, I am curious to know as like we can see traces in jaeger, Where we can also see microservice request/response payload(json) traffic along in  Istio?

I am not interested in the application logs, because its little difficult to related with the traces.

Please help, it will become very helpful in debugging.

Comment: Are you looking for access logs in istio-proxy?

Comment: If possible I would like to see in Jaeger along with traces so that I can relate also while debugging.

Comment: Request you to check following links https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/diagnostic-tools/component-logging/ , https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/logs/access-log/